# how to attach file in android using gmail

Tags: android

```
((HomeActivity) getActivity()).contactus
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        sendEmail();
                    }
                });

        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).attachmentimageview
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                                MY_INTENT_CLICK);
                    }
                });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == MY_INTENT_CLICK) {
                if (null == data)
                    return;

                String selectedImagePath;
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                selectedImagePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(
                        getActivity(), selectedImageUri);
                Log.i("Image File Path", "" + selectedImagePath);
//              txta.setText("File Path : \n" + selectedImagePath);
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendEmail() {
        try {


            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] recipients = new String[] { "Enter email" };
            emailIntent
                    .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
            emailIntent
                    .putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                            new String[] { "anilkumar@softageindia.com,danyalozair@gmail.com" });
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "Feedback");

            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedImagePath );

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    Html.fromHtml(""));
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HI"
                    + "\n\n" + contactustext.getText().toString());
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(emailIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my code i want to attach file from Sd card or gallery i am using given code i am able to get path from galley  But when i click on contact Us Button then it same work to get file directory if we not use attachment then it work properly with text please check where am doing wrong and how to fix it please suggest me actully i want send some text and also with attachment send via gmail when i click on button contact us it redirect to attachment and text to gmail then we can send it .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create this method in your `Activity` or `Fragment` outside of `onCreate`

```
public static void getVcardString() {   

String path = null;     
String vfile = null;

 vfile = "Contacts.vcf";           
Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);

phones.moveToFirst();
Log.i("Number of contacts", "cursorCount" +phones.getCount());  
for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)   {       

     String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
     Log.i("lookupKey", " " +lookupKey);
     Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
     AssetFileDescriptor fd;

     try  {
         fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
         FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
         byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
         fis.read(buf);
         String VCard = new String(buf);          

         path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
         FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
         mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());    

         phones.moveToNext();               

         filevcf = new File(path);
         Log.i("file", "file" +filevcf);

     }catch(Exception e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();  
     }
}       
Log.i("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");          
}
```

and call it inside `onCreate` like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);     
 getVcardString();           
 }
```

And now again, create a new method to send `Email` outside of `onCreate` like :

```
protected void data() {             
File filelocation = filevcf ;     
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");      
sharingIntent.setType("application/x-vcard");       
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "mail@gmail.com" );        
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,    Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));            
}
```

And call this `data()` method `onClick` of your send email button like :

```
data();
```

Please let me know if you get any problem now.

Comment: what is xmlFilename name ?

Comment: The name of your file.

Comment: please check my code i am doing same thing But Problem is coming On attachment button and send button both behave like same please check and edit my code

Comment: What do you mean? You attach file when gmail opens or you're adding by code??

Comment: see there is 2 button on for attach file and another for send mail

Comment: Will you please post complete class?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/DdqRPTFtKh5PCSU8SPFt3C  here is complte code please check am able to send mail when i enter only text but Probelm is coming when i attach file polease check

Answer (score 0):

you can attach file as :

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");      
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Please find attachment");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+"you file's path"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Attach using..."));
```

Comment: please check my code i am doing same thing But Problem is coming On attachment button and send button both behave like same please check and edit my code

Comment: look my code contactus and attachments Button we have call different thing but it behave same please tell me how to fix it